# Finding duplicate code block in SQL queries

Tags: sql

Is there any tool that can highlight duplicate code block in sql queries so that those can be written once and then that definition can be used with alias.

eg:

```
SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01)
is repeated many times in the query
.
..
..
(rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) AS 'Stock'
..
..
..
..
CASE WHEN (rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) 
OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) + od.Number01) - od.Number01 > 0 THEN od.Number01 ELSE (CASE WHEN (rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) 
+ od.Number01) > 0 THEN (rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) + od.Number01) ELSE 0 END) END AS 'Allocated'
```

I want to identify `SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01)` how many times these have been used in the query.

Comment: Can't you just use Ctrl+F in your editor?

Comment: ye, Ctrl+F is the way

Comment: that depends on how long is the query. if it is small sure. but if it is long and there are formatting changes I cant find it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case they are right - just Ctrl+f.

if you have a lot of sql queries to check you may want to look at something else.
Not sure if the code analysis tools check sql as well? some may do as it is just text, but problem is if they just check text they might not take into account space or line breaks.

Alternatively you can knock up your own code to search through all files/folders - take out all line breaks and spaces and treat as string search. Problem is that it won't pick up variables swapped around.

but otherwise, Ctrl+F is your friend...

Comment: yep he is a true friend for sure. I am looking for some tools that does the job for me :)